# ListView + single textview in each item = excessive garbage collecting

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

First of all I have a simple `ListView`. Implementing the `BaseAdapter` and utilizing the ViewHolder pattern I simply have a `TextView` that on each `getView()` call sets the text with a different `String`. Each string has various lengths and it can break into multiple lines.

The excessive garbage collecting occurs when you scroll, it is caused by the `StaticLayout` that is used inside of the `TextView` class. It is creating `float[]`'s and then the garbage collector collects them and causes a stutter in my `ListView`'s scrolling. I came to this conclusion after tracking my scrolling through the Allocation Tracker. Note that excessive is not that it is collection huge chunks of memory but lots of small ones.

Since I am running into this problem even when I simplify my code down to the basics I assume someone has run into this before me. Because this is a system bug and not something I can work around while still using the `TextView`, what do you suggest I use as a workaround for this bug?

Comment: Youre probably doing something wrong. Post your code.

Comment: +1 to the above. Post code, or it's impossible to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the behavior, although I still do not understand why it happened. In my `ListView` I was setting the cacheColorHint as `#00000000` and this was causing problems when combined with my global theme settings of `android:windowBackground=@null` and `android:windowContentOverlay=@null`. I don't understand why it would cause excessive GC nor why simply changing the cacheColorHint to `#FFFFFFFF` would effect it, but what the drawing hierarchy of Android does not always follow the most obvious path.